# Wordpress как сделать аутентификацию со стороннего ресурса?

Tags: wordpress, аутентификация

Как сделать аутентификацию со стороннего ресурса, на подобии Google,Facebook.

У меня есть сервис на который я отправляю логин и пароль, в ответ приходят данные пользователя(unique id, role и т.д.). 
Далее, на стороне WP мне нужно сохранять дополнительные данные пользователя(name, email, address,...), и работать с ними.

Как реализовать привязку ID(стороннего сервиса) с пользователем на стороне WP?

Заранее, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

У пользователя доп. поля хранятся в user_meta. Чтобы добавить поля для юзера используйте ф-цию `update_user_meta`, а считать ее можно с помощью `get_user_meta`.

Пример:

```
global $current_user;

update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'fb_token', 'my_token' );
$token = get_user_meta( $current_user, 'fb_token', true );
```